# Ubuntu on Lenovo Y700 (2016)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lenovo

hello dear ubuntu fans,

my passion for gaming made me switch from a macbook to the lenovo y700. i thought i'm going to dual boot the laptop with win10 for gaming and ubuntu for programming.

i partitioned the internal SSD in a 70GB partition i want to use for the ubuntu.

NOW:

using the UEFI menue to boot i can select the USB drive with 15.10 on it. I can select if i want to try or install ubuntu. Selecting either option results in a ubuntu loading screen, and after this screen the lenovo logo pops up and the laptop boots in windows 10... i really have no idea what the issue might be, i did a lot of googleing to find a similar question but couldn't find anything that could help.

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable secure boot. 
Disable UEFI and change it to leagacy support. 
Disable fast boot.

And you also need kernel 4.4 so i use ubuntu 16.04 lts on my lenovo y700 .

Comment: hello, disabling UEFI and legacy support worked for me thank you! now one little issue, when i boot my laptop it boots into the linux menue, where i can choose which operating system i want to boot, if i select windows, it boots something different than my windows 10, any idea by chance?

Comment: What do you medan with something different ?

Comment: @Hyltixa do you have any performance problem with ubuntu on y700? I want to buy y700 and I also want to use it with ubuntu for programming and windows for game

Comment: I Really confused about buying a mac or this laptop. the price is very cheaper for y700. I develop android application

Comment: Hey!
When i wanted to boot windows again i needed to change back UEFI i think. I dont have a lenovo y700 anymore so not sure :).

Performance was excellent on the lenovo, no problem at all, except for the need of at least kernel 4,4 to get the wifi working :).