# Lenovo IdeaPad Y700-17 with Ubuntu

Tags: ideapad

Has anyone installed Ubuntu on Lenovo IdeaPad Y700-17 (80Q0001MUS) 
either the newest ubuntu or older.  I just need to know it will work with ubuntu before purchasing it.

17.3" 1920x1080 frameless anti-glare UPS LED LCD

Intel Core i7-6700HQ 2.6GHz (Turbo Boost up to 3.5GHz) Quad-Core SKYLAKE

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 4GB discrete graphics

8GB DDR4-2133MHz RAM, 1TB HDD + 128GB SSD

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as a hardware recommendation question.

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup very,very similar to this, and I got Ubuntu 14.04.4 working on it. It's okay; I had problems getting wifi up and running and now I'm having problems with the wifi cutting out every so often (multiple times a day). I got it to install just fine by disabling secure boot and fast boot and by disabling UEFI and booting with legacy support. You can see all that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743996/ubuntu-on-lenovo-y700-2016).

Also, once I got it installed I was having graphics card issues with the Nvidia card, so I just switched to the internal card in BIOS and it was fine after that. I don't care about using the Nvidia card, though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.   For the wifi, check this site in case you have not seen it.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2308296

Comment: And for Nvidia I found this web link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316